# Selecting an additional empty row that does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include a blank row in query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089336/include-a-blank-row-in-query-results)

I would like to add an empty row to my result set at the very top of my SQL query.

The query I am using is this:

```
SELECT 
    PROFILETITLE, DOCID 
FROM
    PROFILES
WHERE 
    COMPANYCODE = ? 
ORDER BY 
    PROFILETITLE
```

Comment: What is an empty row? Assuming that `DOCID` is an `int`, define empty for an integer.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry - an row that gives an blank result for that row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `union all`

```
SELECT null as PROFILETITLE, null as DOCID 
UNION ALL
SELECT PROFILETITLE, DOCID 
FROM PROFILES
WHERE COMPANYCODE=? 
ORDER BY PROFILETITLE
```

but if you wont to add header, and if `DOCID`  is `int` type, you have to use `union all` and `cast` as below

```
SELECT 'PROFILETITLE' as PROFILETITLE, 'DOCID' as DOCID 
UNION ALL
SELECT PROFILETITLE, CAST ( DOCID AS varchar(30) )
FROM PROFILES
WHERE COMPANYCODE=? 
ORDER BY PROFILETITLE
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT '' AS PROFILETITLE, 0 AS DOCID
UNION ALL
SELECT PROFILETITLE, DOCID
FROM PROFILES WHERE COMPANYCODE = ? 
ORDER BY PROFILETITLE
```

Note that when using `UNION`, and all other set operations, columns have to be matched in types, So you have to alias the first two empty values with `PROFILETITLE` and `DOCID`. And you have to watch out the types of the two columns as well to be matched in order to work properly. May be you need to select `NULL` instead of `''` and `0`.

Comment: yes: [SQL-Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3144b/3)

Answer (score 3):

You could add an "empty row" if all columns are `varchar` and empty means `''` in this way:

```
SELECT PROFILETITLE, DOCID 
FROM PROFILES
WHERE ...

UNION ALL

SELECT '' AS PROFILETITLE, '' AS DOCID

ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN PROFILETITLE='' AND DOCID='' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
, PROFILETITLE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL `Union`

```
SELECT PROFILETITLE, DOCID 
FROM PROFILES
WHERE COMPANYCODE=? ORDER BY PROFILETITLE
UNION ALL
SELECT 0, '' 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

You can replace SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 with your temporary table

Answer (score 0):

a union all would do the job

```
SELECT 
'' as PROFILETITLE,
'' as DOCID
UNION ALL
SELECT PROFILETITLE, DOCID 
FROM PROFILES
WHERE COMPANYCODE=? ORDER BY PROFILETITLE
```